# How do I filter and select inside a expanded collection on Microsoft Graph?

Tags: api, odata, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, restful-url

This code works

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root?$filter=Size eq 0&$expand=children($select=id,folder,name,parentReference,cwebUrl)&$select=Id,folder,name,parentReference,children,webUrl
```

I want to filter inside the children:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root?$filter=Size eq 0&$expand=children($select=id,folder,name,parentReference,cwebUrl&$filter=Size eq 0)&$select=Id,folder,name,parentReference,children,webUrl
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When filtering/selecting within an expand, you need to use `;` as the separator, not `&`. So your URL should be:

[https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root?$filter=Size eq 0&$expand=children($select=id,folder,name,parentReference,cwebUrl;$filter=Size eq 0)&$select=Id,folder,name,parentReference,children,webUrl](https://graph.microsoft.com:443/v1.0/me/drive/root?$filter=Size%20eq%200&$expand=children($select=id,folder,name,parentReference,cwebUrl;$filter=Size%20eq%200)&$select=Id,folder,name,parentReference,children,webUrl)

Here is an example of a URL on the TripPin example OData service to show this in action:

[http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips($select=TripId,Name,Description;$filter=TripId eq 0)](http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinServiceRW/People?$expand=Trips($select=TripId,Name,Description;$filter=TripId%20eq%200))

Comment: Does not work for Microsoft Graph... for example: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=memberOf($select=id,displayName;$filter=displayName eq 'Legal')&$select=Id,memberOf` is not able to filter the "Legal" groups or users that only contain it.